# How to Set JPG/PNG file as a Theme?

Tags: android, android-emulator, themes

How to Set JPG/PNG file as a Theme of Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Create drawable/background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Create values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And apply this theme to your activity or application in manifest.xml:

`android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"`

This theme applies the default image (icon.png) to the property windowBackground.

Comment: Not Only for one Application but Whole Mobile Device/Emulator.

Comment: The theme for the device/emulator is much more than single jpg/png file. Or if you want to change the wallpaper - long click on desktop->Personalize display->Wallpaper-> and select the image you need.

Comment: I need to set theme to mobile device.